# Custom attribute Not fetchable from li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-attributes

I have following Code/Structure, what I am trying to do is to hide a div if a custom attribute matches. The problem at the moment is that I can't get the custom attribute as demonstrated in this code:

```
  var elementToHide = 'file_type';
        jQuery('#search-img-ctrl').each(function() {
            var locationli = jQuery(this).find('li').attr(elementToHide);
            alert(locationli);
            alert(elementToHide); // I can't get the custom attribute
            if (locationli != elementToHide) {
                jQuery(this).find('.search-img-box').hide();
            } else {
                jQuery(this).find('.search-img-box').show();
            }
        });
```

And following is my HTML Structure.

```
<div id="search-img-ctrl" class="search-img-ctrl">
 <div class="sampages" style="display: block;">
  <div class="search-img-box sampageitems">
   <a href="image_detail.php">
   <img id="imageimage_array" width="277" height="206" src="upload/2014-05-02-14-05-512014-04-08-14-04-40000560_d.png" alt="">
   </a>
   <br>
   <ul>
    <li> Name </li>
    <li>upload/2014-05-02-14-05-512014-04-08-14-04-40000560_d.png</li>
    <li>identity </li>
    <li>Modify</li>
    <li latitude="null">Latitude</li>
    <li>null</li>
    <li longitude="null">Longitude</li>
    <li>null</li>
    <li model="null">model</li>
    <li>null</li>
    <li file_type="png">model</li>
    <li>png</li>
    <li> Image Size </li>
    <li>11Kb</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try: `var locationli = jQuery(this).find('li['+elementToHide+']');`

Comment: I see `jQuery('#search-img-ctrl').each` do you have more than one element with ID `search-img-ctrl`. Also for custom attribute also prefix it with `data-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally under html5 you should suffix your custom attributes with `data-` prefix. However, in your code to find the li that has specific attribute, use:

```
var locationli = jQuery(this).find('li[' + elementToHide + ']');
```

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/wANxV/

Answer (score 1):

The main wrapper have id and class same value. This is not a good.
Put a numer or other after your id value (id="search-img-ctrl-1" etc) , then do each cycle on class not on id

```
JQuery.each('.search-img-ctrl');
```

Put attributes in your markup with 'data' prefix (as Satpal said) and other thig you can use directly the selector

```
var locationli = jQuery(this).find("li["+elementToHide+"]");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code reads the attribute of the first found element, but it does not filter on it:

```
var locationli = jQuery(this).find('li').attr(elementToHide);
```

A filter might look something like this:

```
var locationli = jQuery(this).find('li')
                 .filter(function(){
                     return $(this).attr(elementToHide);
                 });
```

But obviously closure's method is much shorter.  And keypaul is right, using `data-` prefix is the right way to store your own metadata on elements.

Answer (score 1):

the answers to use `li[' + elementToHide + ']` are good ones, but to help you understand what you are experiencing

### let's break down this line of code:

```
var locationli = jQuery(this).find('li').attr(elementToHide);
```

as you know, `jQuery(this).find('li')` returns all of the decendants of `this` which are `li`'s, and in your example, there are 14 of these.

#### What does `.attr()` return when applied to a set of 14 elements?

I guess it could return an array, a concatenation, who knows?, but the writers of jQuery decided to just return the attribute corresponding to the first element in the set.  In this case, you are calling `.attr(elementToHide)` on `<li>Name</li>`.  This element does not have the "file_type" attribute, therefore, you get an empty string in return.

Here's a quick fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/pmn4/B9bqK/

---

to solve your problem, use either the techniques described by @keypaul and @closure or use [jQuery's filter method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-functionindex)